# Can't get submodule to import properly in another app

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I'm building a couple of Python libraries/apps. I'm still relatively new to Python, and I struggle a lot with the import system. I think I've got a good handle on it for intra-app/module imports, but I'm now trying to import modules from a library I'm building for public release into my other project, and I flat out can't get it to recognize submodules for import.

The library in question is https://github.com/utoxin/PyChance

And I'm trying to import the 'SimpleTable' class from pychance/data/simpletable_class.py. I've tried multiple different import statements, and even different organizations of the library including moving simpleable.py up to the top-level directory, and various import lines in the library's **init**.py files.

My IDE suggests

```
from pychance import SimpleTable
```

with my current setup, but then immediately says that it can't find a reference to that in **init**.py.

If I try things like

```
from pychance.data import SimpleTable
```

it doesn't recognize that 'data' exists.

I'm probably missing something basic, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**ERRATUM**

The PyChance package contains the following source files:

```
pychance/__init__.py
pychance/pychance_class.py
pychance/data/__init__.py
pychance/data/simpletable_class.py
pychance/parsing/__init__.py
pychance/parsing/parser.py
pychance/utility/__init__.py
pychance/utility/singleton.py
```

Source of `pychance/data/__init__.py`:

```py
from .simpletable_class import SimpleTable
```

Source of `pychance/data/simpletable_class.py`:

```py
import random


class SimpleTable:
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

(*) source code is truncated.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it more concisely. A multi-tier directory structure with relevant init files and class files is difficult to represent clearly in a single question.

Comment: Just added some edits that I hope explain the answer to that question.

Comment: Yes, that does help; thank you. I'd probably start by trying to figure out what's being imported under the `pychance` name, and whether it is what you expect it to be (inspecting `pychance.__file__` can be helpful, depending on how it's installed). If `pychance` is coming from somewhere that doesn't have a `data/__init__.py` under it, that's a big, hopefully-useful clue.

Comment: Alright. I'll start digging around using the REPL, and see what I can figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the packaging of `PyChance`, the 2 following imports are functionals:

```py
from pychance.data.simpletable_class import SimpleTable
from pychance.data import SimpleTable
```

I encounter no issue with PyCharm.

You may have a problem with your IDE.

Comment: Either one results in my IDE complaining that 'data' doesn't exist.

Comment: @Utoxin Are you sure that you have installed the latest version of that project? How did you install it? E.g. you can install in development mode via `pip install -e /path/to/setup.py` which automatically reflects any changes you do in the project.

Comment: @a_guest That's an interesting trick. I'll have to try that one. But yes, I have the latest version. I've been installing it from the PyPI package, and checking the version that's installed, and it's current.

But I may have just discovered that the problem is purely in my IDE. When I do the imports in the REPL, it works properly.

Comment: Okay, this may actually be a correct answer, and the problem may be more about my IDE than about my code. Trying to figure out why the IDE isn't seeing the module correctly now, since the REPL is allowing the import to work cleanly.

Comment: Alright, I'm stumped about why my IDE is breaking currently, but this code is working properly when I just run it in a raw python interpreter. Going to have to be a lot less trusting of my IDE, I guess.

Comment: (My IDE /is/ PyCharm. But something about my interpreter config may be at fault.)

Comment: @Utoxin In PyCharm, try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`, it will rebuild the skeletons and hence update its knowledge about installed packages.

Comment: Thanks! I just re-built the whole interpreter, and that fixed it, but that was probably effectively the same thing.